# How to store date and time in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I am using C# and SQL Server 2005. I want to store date and time in my table. In SQL Server, I use `smalldatetime` datatype. I am using this code.

```
TimeZoneInfo ob1 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, ob1);
```

and insert data through this query

```
insert into tablename (name,sub_date) values (@name,'{0}')",dt.ToShortTimeString()
```

but, the problem is that in my table date and time is stored like this `1/1/1900 5:15:00 PM`. Actual date is not stored. How to store actual date and time in database.

**Note:** I want to show all the records of table according to date and time. So, date and time both are important for me.

Comment: Don't concatenate together your SQL statement - this opens the door to SQL injection attacks! Plus you have to convert your date to a string - bad idea, too. Instead: **use a parametrized** query and use a parameter of type `SqlDbType.DateTime` and all your problems will go away!

Comment: Of course - if you call `.ToShortTimeString()`, you're **explicitly** telling .NET to strip away the **date portion** and just leave the time - nothing else....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Define insert statement with parameters
string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.tablename (name, sub_date) VALUES (@name, @mydate)";

// setup connection and command objects
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your-connection-string-here"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, conn))
{
    // add parameters to command
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ".....";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt;

    // open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

That should do the trick! No messy conversion from `DateTime` to string - the `DateTime` value is preserved "as is" and stored in that same format in SQL Server. By using parameters, you've both eliminated the possibility of a SQL injection attack, and also, this query can be re-used if you need to call it multiple times with different values, thus increasing performance, too!

Answer (score 1):

Use a parametrized query and pass the DateTime through as parameter. Using strings is always a bad idea (especially strings that aren't culture-invariant).

Comment: Can u give me any example of parametrized query.

Comment: @Viktor, I think you may already be using one, since you have `@name` in your SQL statement. Edit your question to include the full SQL invocation in C# and I'll show you how to modify it. Oh, and the English word for adressing someone is "you", not "u".

Comment: Ok! But, my problem is not the sql injection, I'll takecare of it, my problem is to store actual date and time in database in India standard time. How to do this, can you give me an example of this?

Comment: I didn't even mention SQL injection... using paramterized queries is the way to go for many reasons, one of which is SQL injection, but also because of the data types, efficiency (no need to convert to and from strings), query re-use (queries can be cached by optimizer even if the parameter contents differ) etc.